# How to disable all logs?

Tags: linux, logging

Is it possible to disable logging on Linux (Ubuntu)?

Need to turn off the `svn`, `jabber`, `apache`, `proftpd`, `sendmail`, `ssh`, `vpn`, `mysql` and all system logs.

Comment: we have a small home server. not very satisfied with his speed. try any method to enlarge it. Of course we can update the hardware, but I wonder whether you can do without it;)
I know turn off the logs is bad. But still want to exeperimental

Answer (score 35):

Syslog has been replaced by rsyslog on numerous OS. So, on Debian > 5, Ubuntu > 11.2, Centos 6.x the following command line would stop it:

```
 service rsyslog stop
```

Then, you can disable it at boot:

```
 systemctl disable rsyslog
```

to enable it again at boot:

```
 systemctl enable rsyslog
```

Comment: This is just what I needed. I have an SBC running on an SDCARD, and the constant writes from logging will certainly kill the SD. Now the system is running consistently, I don't really need logging, so disabling will increase the lifespan of my device considerably.

Comment: On Ubuntu 18.04 (and maybe others), `rsyslog.service` has an alias `syslog.service` which triggers automatic socket activation through `syslog.socket`. On such systems, an additional `systemctl stop syslog.socket` and `systemctl disable syslog.socket` are needed.

Answer (score 5):

If you went disable syslog, please running this command:

```
sudo systemctl disable rsyslog
```

Comment: Warning: Stopping rsyslog.service, but it can still be activated by:
  syslog.socket

Answer (score 4):

Stop Log Daemon *syslogd*.

For example by using init-scripts:

```
/etc/init.d/syslogd stop
```

Depending on your Linux-Dist this can be achived in different ways. For disable logging permanantly (embedded system with low disk space) remove loggind deamons, edit /etc/defaults or remove init scripts from the rc (runlevel-configuration) directories.

Edit: much more of interest would be, what causes your latency problems. I do not believe the logs would cause this. Run "top -d1" and check the most upper processes. A network home server for example would probably not need the XWindow System. If you are not running web-development on this machine also Database and Webser will probably be of no need... A lot of processes can cause lags.

Comment: An init script to stop a service? Why not disable the service?

Comment: May because sysvinit was the old way of managing services? `systemd` just wasn't the way to go 4 years ago (Debian).

Comment: Ah okay, was it impossible to disable logging? Stopping it after startup seems weird. (It'll most likely still log until startup?). But it can in deed be a decent workaround for onder systems, you have my upvote.

Comment: You can disable it by unlinking it from rc.d or edit defaults file in /etc. Today one would of course call systemctl.

Answer (score 3):

if you are running **systemd**, issuing the command below:

```
systemctl disable syslog
```

Answer (score 2):

If (like some of us) you have really old legacy systems:

```
% /etc/init.d/syslog stop
% chkconfig syslog off
```